# Available methods in gradle closure

Tags: gradle, groovy

How do we know what available methods are in Gradle Closures? E.g.:

```
task greeting {
    dependsOn greeting0

    doLast {
        println("hi")
    }
}
```

In the above closure passed into task `greeting`, where do the Gradle specific `dependsOn` & `doLast` come from?

Both `dependsOn` and `doLast` are [`Task`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html) methods. However, if we take a look at the [Project doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#task-java.lang.String-groovy.lang.Closure-), the closure is only a simple Groovy [Closure](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-3.0.10/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Closure.html?is-external=true).

Comment: Gradle scripts are a DSL. Inside that closure, Task (or the subclass of Task you've selected) is the delegate of the closure

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates. How do we know what class would be the delete of the current closure? E.g.: Not only the task closure can have `Task` methods, the closure can also access `Project` method like `copy`

Comment: The whole script has Project as a delegate, so if there's nothing found in Task, it will call the Project method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an example, here's a Groovy DSL script which shows what's going on (I hope)

```
class Example {

    def missingMethod(String name, args) {
        println name
    }
    
    static run(Closure cl) {
        def project = new Project()
        cl.delegate = project
        cl.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
        cl.call()
    }
}

class Project {

    def task(taskDefinition) {
        def task = new Task()
        taskDefinition[0].delegate = task
        taskDefinition[0].resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
        taskDefinition[0].call()
    }

    def and(String what) {
        println "Project $what"
    }
    
    def methodMissing(String name, args) {
        args
    }
}

class Task {

    def say(String what) {
        println "Task $what"
    }
}

// So now we can "run" a script
Example.run {

    task woo {
        say "hello" // From task
        and "world" // From project
    }
}
```

This prints

```
Task hello
Project world
```