# What should we assume about Groovy method parameters without "def" keyword

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have seen this answer from another so post ([Available methods in gradle closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74295987/available-methods-in-gradle-closure)),

```
class Example {

    def missingMethod(String name, args) {
        println name
    }
    
    static run(Closure cl) {
        def project = new Project()
        cl.delegate = project
        cl.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
        cl.call()
    }
}

class Project {

    def task(taskDefinition) {
        def task = new Task()
        taskDefinition[0].delegate = task
        taskDefinition[0].resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
        taskDefinition[0].call()
    }

    def and(String what) {
        println "Project $what"
    }
    
    def methodMissing(String name, args) {
        args
    }
}

class Task {

    def say(String what) {
        println "Task $what"
    }
}

// So now we can "run" a script
Example.run {

    task woo {
        say "hello" // From task
        and "world" // From project
    }
}
```

But I still could not grasp the part where `task` is called, and where the `taskDefinition` is regarded as an array (as in `taskDefinition[0]`)?

```
    task woo {
        say "hello" // From task
        and "world" // From project
    }
```

How can a task is called as such? Can anyone explain more detail about this?